# Error "ran out of stackspace" with jQuery click event in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, internet-explorer-11, stack-overflow

I am working with Highcharts and want to display different data sets on button click. I am loading in an external .js file because the server where the visualization is hosted doesn't not support uploading JSON files.

It works fine on Chrome but I get an "out of stack space" error related to jQuery on IE 11.

```
<button id="init">Show initial</button>
<button id="SC">other button</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

```js
var options = {
  //some options 
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  $.each(['GA', 'SC', 'DA', 'init'], function(i, type) {
    $('#' + type).click(function(e) {
      var dataNew, titleName, len;

      if (type === "init") {
        dataNew = data_GA;
        titleName = "inital state";
        len = 20
      } else if (type === "SC") {
        dataNew = data_SC;
        titleName = "another state";
      }

      chart.update({
        series: [{
          data: dataNew,
          layoutAlgorithm: {
            linkLength: len
          }
        }],
        title: {
          text: titleName
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The different datasets should load on click of the html buttons. Nothing happens apart from the error in the console.

Comment: An error like that normally implies some kind of infinite loop or recursion, however I can't see anything which would cause that in the code you've posted.

Comment: Agree with Rory, you could try to add some debugger in your Javascript code and debug it to find if it has any infinity looping function or unexpected code. Here is an article about [How to Repair the Error "Javascript Is Out of Stack Space" for Free](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-repair-the-error-javascript-is-out-of-stack-space-for-free), you could check it.